# Can you maintain concentration on non-spell abilities (that require it) while raging?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, barbarian, concentration, rage

There are a few class features in the game that require concentration, but are not spells: A Trickery Cleric's Invoke Duplicity, a Glamour Bard's Mantle of Command, a Graviturgist Wizard's Adjust Density, etc. They are all phrased in a similar way concerning concentration:

> for 1 minute, or until you lose your concentration (as if you were concentrating on a spell).

Going into a rage stops you from keeping concentration on a spell:

> If you are able to cast spells, you can't cast them or concentrate on them while raging.

But, if a multiclassed character (with one of the above subclasses, plus barbarian) uses such a concentration-based feature then goes into a rage, are they able to maintain concentration on that feature?

For example: Timmy the Trickery Cleric/Barbarian uses Invoke Duplicity, then enters a rage. Is Timmy able to continue concentrating on Invoke Duplicity?

Comment: Related: [Does Rage Prevent Divine Smite?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/86745/does-rage-prevent-divine-smite), [Can a multiclassed barbarian/cleric use their Channel Divinity while raging?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/137677/can-a-multiclassed-barbarian-cleric-use-their-channel-divinity-while-raging), [Can a Sun Soul Barbarian make his ranged spell attack while raging?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/116135/can-a-sun-soul-barbarian-make-his-ranged-spell-attack-while-raging)

Answer (score 13):

### No, you can't, because they require concentrating "as if" on a spell

As you note, the barbarian's [Rage](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/barbarian#Rage-51) feature says:

> If you are able to cast spells, you can’t cast them or concentrate on them while raging.

The [Trickery Domain cleric](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/cleric#TrickeryDomain)'s [Invoke Duplicity](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/cleric#ChannelDivinity:InvokeDuplicity-155) Channel Divinity option says (PHB, p. 63; emphasis mine):

> As an action, you create a perfect illusion of yourself that lasts for 1 minute, or until you lose your concentration **(as if you were concentrating on a spell)**.

Because you need to maintain concentration on the illusion "as if you were concentrating on a spell", anything that prevents concentrating on a spell also prevents you from concentrating on something "as if" it were a spell.

Rules designer Jeremy Crawford unofficially confirms this interpretation in [this January 2018 tweet](https://www.sageadvice.eu/2018/04/03/can-you-concentrate-on-invoke-duplicity-while-raging/), in response to a now-deleted question that specifically asks about the Invoke Duplicity feature:

> *Can you concentrate on Invoke Duplicity while Raging?*
>
> **You can't concentrate on a spell while you rage. This prohibition applies to abilities like Invoke Duplicity that require you to concentrate on them as if they were spells.**

Rage specifies that you can't concentrate on spells while raging; the same restrictions apply to things that require you to maintain concentration "as if you were concentrating on a spell". As far as I know, all official non-spell features that require concentration in this way specify that you do so "as if you were concentrating on a spell", and so Rage prevents the character from concentrating on any of these features.

Comment: In Tasha's Cauldron of Everything there is the Favored Foe optional class feature for the Ranger. It requires concentration "as if concentrating on a spell" and so this interpretation is relevant.